# Amazon ec2 - Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, memory, java

I don't have any experience of working with servers, so please explain your answer in detail or provide a link to support your answer.

I want to restart server and executing command for that gives error

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

The case is that server was not responding number of API calls made concurrently and was throwing the error

```
(12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
```

Suddenly, server went down while executing requests.

Now, I think I need to restart the server and I tried that using below command and getting the mentioned error.

```
ec2-reboot-instances i-idOfInstance
```

Doing `ulimit-a` gives below information :

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 4566
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: That's a Java error. Are you getting this on your local machine while executing this (using ec2-tools) or on the remote machine itself?

Comment: @NathanC I execute on remote machine. On local, it says `ec2-reboot-instances command not found`.

Comment: You don't have enough RAM in your instance to run your Java VM, use the `-Xmx` flag in your `java` call to limit the amount of memory Java uses and/or re-size to a bigger instance.

Comment: @LinuxDevOps Which `java` call? Currently I am not able to do anything. Server is down and I am finding how to make it up.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed where that error was (client or server), you want to run the ec2 reboot command on another machine or use the AWS web Console

Comment: @LinuxDevOps I want to run that command on another machine by logging into server using key.